# CSS inheritance on sub dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, inheritance, drop-down-menu

I am working on a school project and am building a nice looking multi level dropdown menu for my page. I have not been able to get the display of the sub-menu to change on hover when targeting the parent li element. I think it might be an inheritance issue but am unsure.

I am still pretty new to this so I could have royally botched the classes/ids and levels of inheritance I am using in the css.

So far I have also tried different combinations of inheritance and using the classes and ids in different elements, I have tried using >, I have tried different display modes, I have tried using visibility instead of display, I have tried different position.

If there is a better way to set this up to make this work? Am I missing something obvious, as usual?

Here is a snippit

```css
/*====================================MAIN=================================*/
body {
    background-color: #d5d3d5;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', 'Calibri', 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.flex_body {
    background:linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,.0), rgba(255,255,255,1) 20%);
    display: flex;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 800px;
}

.page_body {
    background:linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,.0), rgba(255,255,255,1) 15%);
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    height: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
}   
/*=============================MAIN=NAVIGATION=================================*/
#header {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: inset 0px -15px 18px -6px rgba(121, 104, 124, 0.678);
    text-align: right;
}

#navBar {
    list-style-type: none; 
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 80px 0px 0px 0px
}

#navBar li {
    font-size: 18px; 
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px; 
    margin: 0px 0px -10px 0px;
    
}

#navBar li:not(:last-child){   
    border-right: 1px solid #8f85a1dc;
}

#headNAV ul li a {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 40px 20px 40px; 
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #353138;
}

#navBar li a:hover{
    background-color: #50328ddc;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }

#headNAV ul li input{
    margin: 5px 35px 10px 35px;
}

/*======================news-dropdown============================*/

#news-dropdown {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 21px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 140px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#navBar #news-dropdown li {
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px -35px;
    border: none; 
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
}

#navBar #news-dropdown li:not(:last-child){   
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aea7bb8c;
}

#navBar #news-dropdown ul li a{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px 25px;
}

#navBar li:hover #news-dropdown {
    display: block;
}

#news-dropdown li:hover a{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #50328d;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }

/*======================myPage-Nav============================*/

#myPage_button:hover > #myPage{
    color: white;
}

#myPage_button {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#myPage {
    color: #50328ddc;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#dropdown-btn {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
}

#myPage-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 17px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 182px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#navBar li:hover #myPage-menu {
    display: block;
    
}

#navBar #myPage-menu li {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px -30px;
    border: none; 
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
}

.fa-angle-right {
    float: right;
}

#navBar #myPage-menu li:not(:last-child){   
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aea7bb8c;
}
#navBar #myPage-menu ul li a{
    padding: 10px 40px 10px 20px;
    margin: 0px -15px;
}

#myPage-menu li:hover a{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #50328d;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;
  }


.sub-dropdown {
    display: none; 
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -42px;
    margin-left: 140px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#navBar #myPage-menu ul li:hover .sub-dropdown{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
<header id="header">
    <nav id="headNAV">
      <ul id="navBar">
          <li><a  href= "#" >Mission</a></li>
          <li><a  href= "#" >News<span id = "dropdown-btn" class="fas fa-caret-down"></span></a>
            <div id="news-dropdown">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Politcs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Science</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div> 
        </li>
          <li><a  href= "#" >Events</a></li>
          <li><a  href= "#" >Forums</a></li>
          <li><a  id= 'myPage_button' href= "#" >My<span id='myPage'>Page</span><span id = "dropdown-btn" class="fas fa-caret-down"></span></a>
            <div id="myPage-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Main Feed</a></li>
                    <li class="hover-menu"><a href="#">Projects</a><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></li>
                        <div class="sub-dropdown">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Politcal</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Research</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Creative</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Collaborations</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div> 
                    <li><a href="#">Messages</a><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></li>
                    <div class="sub-dropdown">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Collaborations</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Private</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div> 
                    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div> 
          </li>
          <li><input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..."></li>
          <li><a id="header_login" href= "#" >Login/SignUp</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be a little much at this point but take a look at this menu it helps with the problem you are having the hover effect on takes over on desktop but you can still use the click functionality.  Hope this helps and good luck

https://jsfiddle.net/fLvk091e/1/

```
<nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">mission</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-container">
          <button class="dropdown-btn">news +</button>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">latest news</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">politcs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">science</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">community</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">events</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">forums</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-container">
          <button class="dropdown-btn">myPage +</button>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">see myPage</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">politcal</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">research</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">creative</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">collaborations</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..." /></li>
        <li><a href="#">login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I wasn't having a problem with one displaying and the other not. When I manually change either sub-dropdown to block display they show up fine(It looks like there is only one that pops up because they overlap evenly). It is just I can't get the submenu to change from display none to display block on hover.

Comment: what browser are you using? I checked it in Chrome and the hover effect worked fine it just disappeared when I tried to go from the link or li to the submenu itself.  When you say on hover do you mean when you hover the link/li it wont appear display block or when you try to hover the child div it wont stay display block

Comment: You may be having issues because you have some invalid HTML and some duplicate IDs  you can use an HTML validator to clean some of this up, and let me know if you need anything else. https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: Oh gee willikers! Thanks for the validation reminder. I didn't wrap the <div> within the <li>. Now I see the problem of the space. Is there a way to get the second submenu to show up in line with the link it is attached to without having to give it its own class/id? Also for some reason the entire sub menu inherited the color change for the anchor tags. I will have to dig into that as well

Comment: @KevinMcGreal went ahead and edited my original post have a look at the jsfiddle you don't have to use it because you are pretty far along but it should help you better understand responsive and accessible navigations. You can even takes steps to make it more accessible. good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look to figure out how I can implement this in the future. For now I will create a separate class for the second sub menu and style each individually. I was hoping for a more concise method but it is not a huge deal. You put a lot of time into this and I really appreciate it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231279/discussion-between-kjek-code-and-kevin-mcgreal).